バネの動きをするプログラムの考え方
下記にバネの動きをするというプログラムがありました。
1.2 押し心地を改良する | 1. クッキークリッカーの改良 | Siv3D 勉強会 特設ページ
// ばねの蓄積時間を加算する
springAccumulatedTime += Scene::DeltaTime();

while (0.005 <= springAccumulatedTime)
{
    // ばねの力（変化を打ち消す方向）
    double force = (-0.02 * springX);

    // 画面を押しているときに働く力
    if (cookieCircle.leftPressed())
    {
        force += 0.004;
    }

    // 速度に力を適用（減衰もさせる）
    springVelocity = (springVelocity + force) * 0.92;

    // 位置に反映
    springX += springVelocity;

    springAccumulatedTime -= 0.005;
}

バネに関する方程式で知っているのは、　f = -k*x　くらいなもので、これだと式に時間が入ってないので、他に知っているもので捻り出すと、時間が入っているものだと A*sin(ω*t) くらいなものなのですが、上記コードは A*sin(ω*t) が書かれているプログラムに見えずどのように考えたらいいのかわかっていません。
とはいえ、
// ばねの力（変化を打ち消す方向）
double force = (-0.02 * springX);

の部分が f = -k*x　な気がします。ここからどういう考えで、時間・速度・位置に落とし込まれているのでしょうか？（なお関連ワードとして数値積分が関係していそうな気がするのですが、まだ学んでいるところで、自分で説明できるところまで来ていませんし、方向性が違うかもしれないので、これ以上数値積分について現段階では記載できません）
参考：

単振動：鉛直ばね振り子
単振動の公式まとめ（周期・ばね・エネルギー） | 理系ラボ


この処理では、springAccumulatedTimeを0.005(秒)を単位時間とし、それごとに区切って計算しています。
(最初にspringAccumulatedTimeを加算して、whileループ内でspringAccumulatedTime -= 0.005と減算していることから判断できます)
単位時間(whileループの1回)では、その時間での「ばねの伸び」から力(force)を計算し、ばねが戻る「速度」(springVelocity)を計算しています。
単位時間の速度=ばねが戻る距離、と考えてspringX += springVelocityと「ばねの伸び」を更新しています。
ループごとに「ばねの伸び」を更新するので、徐々に力(force)は小さくなり、バネガ戻る距離も小さくなっていきます。
＃なお、この処理では「力 = 加速度」としている(簡略化している)と推測します。

考え方としては、「ある瞬間のばねの伸びから次の瞬間のばねの伸びを計算する処理を連続して行っている」と考えるのが妥当と思います。
なので、f = -k*xの式はコード(force = (-0.02 * springX))に現れるが、時間は陽には現れない(ループとして表している)のだと思います。
＃そう実現している理由は、cookieCircleを押している場合、力(force)を補正するため、数式で表すのが難しかったからではないかと思います。
